# How do i fix this AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the mrp that is in the _3Ay6Sb _31Dcoz class. It throws an attribute error and I'm stuck. My idea is to scrape 1000 such URLs from Flipkart and not all of them have an MRP listed. How can i fix this?

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "https://www.flipkart.com/realme-c15-power-silver-64-gb/p/itm70ebdb8a0fbdf?pid=MOBFUEPQYF27Y72B"


def get_urls():

    response = requests.get(base_url).text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')

    mrp = soup.find('a', attrs={'class': '_3Ay6Sb _31Dcoz'}).text

    print(mrp)



get_urls()
```

Comment: `find('a', attrs={'class': '_3Ay6Sb _31Dcoz'})` is returning `None` because it can't find the element

Comment: There are some pages where the element is present and there are pages where it is absent. I got the code working for the pages where the element is present. But I need a logic to handle both cases and if-else idea is not working for some reason

Answer (score 0):

I search the page and found out that what you are looking for is  not 
so simply re-write this line to:

```python
mrp = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': '_3Ay6Sb _31Dcoz'}).text
```

Comment: Thanks that works. I'm new to programming and it might sound stupid. But I have another question about it. I am scraping the mobiles category and on some pages, the element I'm looking to scrape is not available and it returns an error with the same code. I know the reason is the element not being there.  An example page is ( https://www.flipkart.com/redmi-9i-nature-green-128-gb/p/itmd8edb00f426bc?pid=MOBFV8RYXZFMAUHM&lid=LSTMOBFV8RYXZFMAUHMYKOQXC ). How do I handle both cases with one block of code, I tried if else but it is not working for some reason.